# Symfony-doctrine: need to set to null a column when i delete his target entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.7

I have a class Zone containing this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Planification", mappedBy="zone")
 */
protected $planifications;
```

and a class Planification with this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Zone", inversedBy="planifications")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="zone_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
 * @Expose
 */
 protected $zone;
```

But when I go to see in database, zone_id isn't set at null when I delete a Zone.
And I have any error code. I only see the zone was deleted, that's all.

But if I configure in another way : "when i delete a zone, i delete the planification", it works :

In zone class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Planification", mappedBy="zone", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"remove"})
 */
protected $planifications;
```

In planification class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Zone", inversedBy="planifications")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="zone_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * @Expose
 */
 protected $zone;
```

But I don't need to delete the planification when a zone is deleted. I need to set zone_id to null.

Any idea ?

Comment: Hi, your first definition is fine.. i don't know why doesn't work.

Comment: I just retrieved the project from another develper has been left. But I see something weird, in dataloadfixture. There is something with "addReference" "getReference", and in database, this is not just an simple id ... maybe that's why it doesn't match with the onDelete.

Comment: The addReference and the getReference are just here to share objects between fixtures. You can find more infos here : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

Comment: yes, I know ... but i'm so lost that I try to get off all possibilities ahah. Finally, I set null with a function in repository file when i deleted the zone ... because I don't find at all ... this is upset me :D

Comment: Can you check the database if a foreign key is set at Planification s table for "zone_id" column to Zone s table id? Try "SHOW CREATE TABLE `planification`;"

Comment: yup !  I saw the foreign key :( ==> CONSTRAINT `FK_6A4EBC3C9F2C3FAB` FOREIGN KEY (`zone_id`) REFERENCES `ikc_zone` (`id`),

Answer (score 1):

You should have

Zone:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Planification", mappedBy="zone")
*/
protected $planifications;
```

Planifications:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Zone", inversedBy="planifications")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="zone_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
* @Expose
*/
protected $zone;
```

Then use

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

if this seems correct use:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

OR:

You could also do something like this I reckon, try it out:

Zone:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Planification", mappedBy="zone", orphanRemoval=true)
*/
protected $planifications;
```

Planifications:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Zone", inversedBy="planifications")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="zone_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
* @Expose
*/
protected $zone;
```

Comment: yeah, that's I do. But, it doesn't work, and i don't know why ...  and my DB is already to INNODB because the delete cascade works. (second example that I wrote). And, I updated the schema database.

Comment: What error do you have with just the `onDelete="SET NULL"` ? This should do the job

Comment: I've any error ... the zone_id column styill has the id as a value.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I could resolve it by changing database engine of my  MySQL database table from MyISAM  to InnoDB  (it was the only table with type = MyISAM):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

After that :

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```